# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, csrf

```
def order_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Order Submitted')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()

    return render_to_response('home/order.html', {'form': form})
```

order_view function in views.py

```html
<form class="form form-table" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy   }}
<input class="btn br-green" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

There is still a CSRF error in it. Have tried most of the solution but they are not working.Have tried adding RequestContext(request) as well.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponseRedirect` takes a url.  I don't think 'Order Submitted' is.

Try

```
def order_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    return render_to_response('home/order.html', {'form': form})
```

If this works then you're sorted and use django.messages to provide the message to your user.

Comment: UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "

Comment: try replacing `render_to_response('home/order.html', {'form': form})` with `render( request, 'home/order.html', {'form': form})`

Comment: please mark answered if has solved your problem so it doesn't show in the unanswered questions